# Error when setting up Release pipeline to Connect to Azure Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a release pipeline that deploy's a web application to an Azure App service.  Everything was working, until I transferred the Azure subscription to another owner.  It has been over 24 hours since the transfer has been completed and still getting the error.

I have granted myself Global Admin role.

Error(s):
Service connection creation operation failed
 Failed to set Azure permission 'RoleAssignmentId: 380a3598-2863-4b12-b8e7-9e80d7d50125' for the service principal 'f0f249b2-2f4b-435b-b7d7-2d5a739b14a6' on subscription ID '834a2851-5d95-4e8e-9196-cb583f4fdb69': error code: Unauthorized, innner error code: InvalidAuthenticationTokenTenant, inner error message The access token is from the wrong issuer 'https://sts.windows.net/0fd08f18-29f8-479b-80d9-8d28b52bab6c/'. It must match the tenant 'https://sts.windows.net/b6ee8e7c-ae9f-4188-8654-65dbbbd2b302/' associated with this subscription. Please use the authority (URL) 'https://login.windows.net/b6ee8e7c-ae9f-4188-8654-65dbbbd2b302' to get the token. Note, if the subscription is transferred to another tenant there is no impact to the services, but information about new tenant could take time to propagate (up to an hour). If you just transferred your subscription and see this error message, please try back later. For troubleshooting refer to link.
Session Id: 0d012481-a910-4b74-981b-bffca782472d

Comment: Does this error occurred on create the service connection? If yes, did you remove the previous  service connection first? Which creation mode do you use while you create service connection? Automatic? Or manual? If it's automatic, please try with manual.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by having my user removed from AD on the account that the subscription was transferred from.